# How to check if a region is selected by mouse?

Tags: region, highlighting, mouse

Usually a mouse selected region is highlighted and a region set by (set-mark-command) is not highlighted. But I don't know a programmatic way to check it.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what it is you want to check? Do you just want to know if the mouse has selected a region and do something if so?

Comment: @RichieHH Yes, I'd like to have a global flag that is true when the region is selected by mouse and is false when the region is selected by running commands from M-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have `transient-mark-mode` switched off. Without `transient-mark-mode` you do not get a highlighted region after setting `mark` with <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> and successive motion commands.

If the region is not highlighted, it is not active and `(region-active-p)` returns nil.

Even if the region is not active `(point)` and `(mark)` can give differing positions. That is the situation without `transient-mark-mode` when you have set `mark` with <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> and moved `point` away from that position.

See also [`use-region-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Region.html) to neglect empty active regions.

Comment: I'm able to use (region-active-p) to achieve my goal with transient-mark-mode switched off. (region-active-p) will return t if it's selected by mouse (and there's also highlighting) and will return nil if the region is set by keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Use **`(mouse-region-match)`**.  `C-h f mouse-region-match` says:

> `mouse-region-match` is a compiled Lisp function in `mouse.el`.
>
> `(mouse-region-match)`
>
> Return non-`nil` if there's an active region that was set with the mouse.

Comment: heh. helm should have found that for me.

Comment: @RichieHH: (Icicles finds it right away.) Even `M-x apropos` finds it, as the first hit, with the highest score, for input keywords `region` and `mouse`.

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work for me. (mouse-region-match) always gives me nil regardless of whether set by mouse.

Comment: Put (mouse-region-mouse) in your *Scratch* buffer than mouse select to the end of it and press C-x e while its still selected with the mouse selection just past the closing ")".

Comment: @Drew yes, I definitely need to use apropos and helm would have shown it had I been rigorous enough. Helm has a super helm-apropos and I should use it more.

Comment: @DataHungry: That's exactly what this function is for. If the region was selected by the mouse then it returns non-`nil`; otherwise it returns `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you want to check for but if you wish to do something when the mouse has selected a region then here is one way to do it using [Emacs advice functionality](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

```elisp
(defun register-mouse-select(&rest args)
  (message "mouse select"))

(advice-add 'mouse-set-region :after #'register-mouse-select)

 ;;(advice-remove 'mouse-set-region #'register-mouse-select)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yet after evaluating these lines, I still don't see any message when I select a region by a mouse.

Comment: sorry, but the dreaded "works for me" with emacs gtk 26 on Debian.